# MySQL query take too much time on new server

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb

I have same database on 2 servers.

**Server 1 (cloud server 4 GB RAM)**

MySQL Variables = https://pastebin.com/raw/jENsXnsK

This is a cloud server (Managed MySQL cloud instance from rackspace) with 4 GB of RAM.

When i execute a query, it have multiple JOINS, it is executed in

```
150 rows in set (0.61 sec)
```

**Server 2 (dedicated 32 GB RAM)**

MySQL Variables = https://pastebin.com/raw/sYdBhp4p

This is a new dedicated server with 32 GB of ram. Not in production yet, we are trying to move cloud server to dedicated as we get more CPU/RAM.

Copied DB from cloud server to this new dedicated, but same query take much more time.

```
150 rows in set (21.32 sec)
```

That is like approx 40 times slower.

Result on free -m on dedicated

```
[root@server1 ~]# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          31797        2700       23182          96        5914       28569
Swap:         16381           0       16381
[root@server1 ~]#
```

In cloud no ssh access, just MySQL access like Amazon RDS.

**EDIT 1:**

I changed join_buffer_size from default 131072 to 2M, that made query execute much faster on dedicated server.

> 150 rows in set (1.84 sec)

Still it is approx 3x times slower than server with 4GB RAM.

(from link + prettyprint)

```
SELECT  nr.*, p.*, e.*, 
    (
        SELECT  cityname as cityname
            FROM  city_type AS ct
            where  ct.id = p.city_type
    ) as cityname, 
    (
        SELECT  city_id as city_id
            FROM  tbl_suburb AS ts
            where  ts.id = e.tbl_suburb_id
    ) as suburb_city_id, 
    (
        SELECT  suburb_name
            FROM  tbl_suburb AS ts
            where  ts.id = e.tbl_suburb_id
    ) as suburb_name, 
    (
        SELECT  kilometers as km
            FROM  tbl_suburb AS tskm
            where  tskm.id = e.tbl_suburb_id
    ) as suburb_kilometers
    FROM  new_registrations AS nr
    INNER JOIN  tbl_admin_registrations AS tar  ON tar.registration_id = nr.id
    INNER JOIN  tbl_admin_properties AS tap  ON tap.admin_id = tar.admin_id
    INNER JOIN  (tbl_properties AS p
            LEFT JOIN  tbl_room_types rt  ON (rt.tbl_property_id = p.id)
                )  ON p.id = tap.property_id
    INNER JOIN  tbl_expansions AS e  ON e.property_id = tap.property_id
    WHERE  p.expansion = '1'
      AND  p.status = '2'
      AND  nr.country = 1
      AND  nr.id NOT IN( 203, 204 )
      AND  ( nr.deleted = 'n'
              OR  nr.deleted IS NULL 
           )
      AND  e.id IN (
        SELECT  te.id as expansion_id
            FROM  tbl_suburb AS ts2
            INNER JOIN  tbl_expansions as te  ON te.tbl_suburb_id IN (
                SELECT  id
                    FROM  tbl_suburb
                    WHERE  city_id IN (
                        SELECT  id
                            FROM  city_type
                            WHERE  country_id = '1')) 
                          )AND (
                  (rt.week4 > 350 AND  rt.week4 <= 5250 )
              OR  (rt.week3 > 350 AND  rt.week3 <= 5250 )
              OR  (rt.week2 > 350 AND  rt.week2 <= 5250 )
              OR  (rt.week1 > 350 AND  rt.week1 <= 5250 ) )
    GROUP BY  nr.id;
```

Comment: Have you compared explain plans for the same query? explain plans are first item to seek for query performance.

Comment: @used-by-already I don't want to change query even if it will speed up as i am not the developer of the application. All i need is same query run same speed in new server. Here is the explain for the query. https://pastebin.com/raw/iiWKDaD7 I am not sure if this is what you need, if you want a diff result, can you please tell the sql to run ?

Comment: I asked if **you** had **compared** the plans. This might reveal a missing index for example, it was a suggestion to assist you narrow down the reasons. It won't help me at all.

Comment: I am not sure how to compare. I have posted actual SQL command in previous reply. Can you please tell what SQL command i run or its more than just one SQL command ?

Comment: Visual comparison, or use any tool that can compare text files. It was just a suggestion, and I'm not comparing 2 sets of server settings either which could also be compared by you.  I'm afraid I can't offer any more.

Comment: by the way, one server is **MySQL** and the other is **MariaDB** so those 2 sets of server settings are impossible to compare simply

Comment: Can we also see the `EXPLAIN` for the other machine.  There are a number of differences between the Optimizers; this might help in discovering what difference bit you.

Comment: I'm surprised you were not in trouble with Server 1 -- 2.5G buffer_pool + 800M key_buffer --> too much memory --> swapping --> slooooow.

Answer (score 0):

- Turn `IN ( SELECT ... )` into `JOIN` wherever possible.  I cringe seeing such nested 3 deep.
- Try to get the needed ids *first*, then join to the other tables.  This avoids the cost of "explode-implode" from `JOIN` + `GROUP BY`.
- Pick between `'n'` and `IS NULL` for `deleted`.  Any use of `OR` is a potential inefficiency.
- `week1..week4`: Usually a bad idea to splay an array across columns.  In this case it leads to an unoptimizable `OR`.
- Yes `join_buffer_size` was too small.  But the `JOIN` buffer is a kludge to work around some of the issues mentioned above.
- Can all the `JOIN` use indexes going either way?  (It is not obvious from the one `EXPLAIN`.  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`, please.)